# Bulk update field using SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables Invoices and payments. Invoice has many payments and I want to update field called `total_payments_amount` for all invoices rows with sum of all associated payments to each one in a single SQL query. So here is what I tried

---

```
UPDATE invoices
SET total_payments_amount = pays.total_amount
FROM invoices inv
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT invoice_id, SUM(amount) as total_amount
  FROM payments
  WHERE invoice_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY invoice_id
) pays
ON inv.id = pays.invoice_id
```

but after running this query I see that all records contain the same value. so what's wrong here?

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Try with cte..

```
;With cte_total
AS ( SELECT invoice_id, SUM(isnull(amount,0)) as total_amount
       FROM payments
       WHERE invoice_id IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY invoice_id)
UPDATE inv
   SET inv.total_payments_amount = c.total_amount
FROM cte_total c
     JOIN invoices inv 
        ON inv.id = c.invoice_id
```

Comment: it doesn't work. All records has been changed with same value.

Comment: Could you please check the 'payments' table.. It may contain same payment information against all the invoices .. Can you provide some sample data and the result that you are expected??